# Heroku: Cannot push to heroku due to NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I ran `git push heroic master` and got this long error message(truncated it). If I'm not wrong, this is the main cause of the problem `remote: NoMethodError: undefined method 'split' for {}:Hash`. How do I solve this problem from the terminal, even though the code runs on local machine. Please inform me if more information is required, and perhaps tell me what's wrong here.

````
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        You have the `.bundle/config` file checked into your repositor
remote:         It contains local state like the location of the installed bundle
remote:         as well as configured git local gems, and other settings that should
remote:        not be shared between multiple checkouts of a single repo. Please
remote:        remove the `.bundle/` folder from your repo and add it to your `.gitignore` file.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        --- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------
remote:        # Error Report
remote:        
remote:        ## Questions
remote:        
remote:        Please fill out answers to these questions, it'll help us figure out
remote:        why things are going wrong.
remote:        
remote:        - **What did you do?**
remote:        
remote:          I ran the command `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment --no-clean`
remote:        
remote:        - **What did you expect to happen?**
remote:        
remote:          I expected Bundler to...
remote:        
remote:        - **What happened instead?**
remote:        
remote:          Instead, what happened was...
remote:        
remote:        - **Have you tried any solutions posted on similar issues in our issue tracker, stack overflow, or google?**
remote:        
remote:          I tried...
remote:        
remote:        - **Have you read our issues document, https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/doc/contributing/ISSUES.md?**
remote:        
remote:          ...
remote:        
remote:        ## Backtrace
remote:        
remote:        ```
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for {}:Hash
remote:          /tmp/build_571ced5049bd8f6d5aa742e589ae07bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:253:in `get_array'
remote:          /tmp/build_571ced5049bd8f6d5aa742e589ae07bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:179:in `without'
remote:          /tmp/build_571ced5049bd8f6d5aa742e589ae07bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:169:in `normalize_groups'
remote:          /tmp/build_571ced5049bd8f6d5aa742e589ae07bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:24:in `run'
remote:          /tmp/build_571ced5049bd8f6d5aa742e589ae07bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:186:in `block in install'
remote:          /tmp/build_571ced5049bd8f6d5aa742e589ae07bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:92:in `temporary'
remote:          /tmp/build_571ced5049bd8f6d5aa742e589ae07bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:185:in `install'
````

.bundle/config

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: ""
```

Comment: Can you put the contents of your .bundle/config ?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the entire terminal output when I run `git push heroku master`, I don't know how to access that file directly

Comment: No, that log is saying the you have the configurations for bundle checked on your git version control, is a config file located on a folder named .bundle inside your project

Comment: I just realised it's a folder that is a "hidden file", uploaded the contents

Comment: Make this simple test, remove that config file and push the changes to heroku

Comment: I have the same error message, do I need to run any commands besides deleting it from my local directory and then running `git push heroku master`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187351/discussion-between-javier-menendez-rizo-and-prashin-jeevaganth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs are warning you about that you have .bundle/config checked on your version control.

Remove from your repo and push your changes

```
rm .bundle/config
rmdir .bundle
```