# LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have successfully pushed my repository from my local computer to heroku after several tries in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373480/heroku-cannot-push-to-heroku-due-to-nomethoderror) and also following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#heroku-gems). However, clicking on both the [git](https://git.heroku.com/arcane-depths-69465.git) and [herokuapp.com link](https://arcane-depths-69465.herokuapp.com) produces error messages. Though the push has many warnings, I tried migrating my database anyway. May I know what is the problem here? Please inform me if more information is required to solve the problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'
  gem 'rails-assets-chosen'
end

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails',        '5.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',           '3.1.11'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'faker',    '1.7.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',   '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',           '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',     '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',       '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',   '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails',   '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',     '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',       '2.7.0'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.11.1'
gem 'bootstrap', '4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'simple_form'





group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end



group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end




# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

config/database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  #adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Output when I run `git push heroku master`

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 441 bytes | 441.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
remote:        Old: ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        New: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching rake 12.3.2
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.10.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.3
remote:        Installing rake 12.3.2
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Fetching erubi 1.8.0
remote:        Installing erubi 1.8.0
remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.4
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.4
remote:        Fetching rack 2.0.6
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.6
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.3.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Fetching arel 9.0.0
remote:        Installing arel 9.0.0
remote:        Fetching mimemagic 0.3.3
remote:        Installing mimemagic 0.3.3
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching bcrypt 3.1.11
remote:        Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.10.0
remote:        Installing ffi 1.10.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching will_paginate 3.1.6
remote:        Installing will_paginate 3.1.6
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Fetching method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Installing method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Fetching thor 0.20.3
remote:        Installing thor 0.20.3
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Fetching pg 0.18.4
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching popper_js 1.11.1
remote:        Installing popper_js 1.11.1
remote:        Fetching puma 3.9.1
remote:        Installing puma 3.9.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rails-assets-chosen 1.8.7
remote:        Installing rails-assets-chosen 1.8.7
remote:        Fetching rails-assets-tether 1.4.3
remote:        Installing rails-assets-tether 1.4.3
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.10.1
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.10.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Installing i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.7.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Installing rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching autoprefixer-rails 9.4.6
remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 9.4.6
remote:        Fetching uglifier 3.2.0
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.2.0
remote:        Fetching marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Installing marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Fetching bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
remote:        Installing bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Installing rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Fetching activesupport 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching faker 1.7.3
remote:        Installing faker 1.7.3
remote:        Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Fetching activemodel 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activemodel 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.7.0
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching sass 3.7.3
remote:        Installing sass 3.7.3
remote:        Fetching activejob 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activejob 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching activerecord 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activerecord 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha6
remote:        Installing bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha6
remote:        Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Fetching actionview 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actionview 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching actionpack 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actionpack 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching actioncable 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching activestorage 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actioncable 5.2.2
remote:        Installing actionmailer 5.2.2
remote:        Installing activestorage 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching railties 5.2.2
remote:        Installing railties 5.2.2
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Fetching simple_form 4.1.0
remote:        Installing simple_form 4.1.0
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Fetching rails 5.2.2
remote:        Installing rails 5.2.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 31 Gemfile dependencies, 71 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from sass:
remote:        
remote:        Ruby Sass is deprecated and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019.
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
remote:          primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
remote:          sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
remote:        
remote:        * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
remote:          http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811
remote:        
remote:        Bundle completed (48.73s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        The latest bundler is 2.0.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.14.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (2.15s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
remote:        /tmp/build_21f3a603c9f764cf4e2758843744dd99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        Detecting rails configuration failed
remote:        set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 49M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v6
remote:        https://arcane-depths-69465.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/arcane-depths-69465.git
   4eb67f4..70f8752  master -> master
```

Running `heroku run rake db:migrate`

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
rake aborted!
LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:952:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:952:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Are you using sqlite on this project?

Comment: Yes I am using it I guess. I followed through a tutorial that uses it.

Comment: I added a default configuration for sqlite3 on a fresh rails app

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the sqlite3 gem to your Gemfile and specify your database on your database.yml

Gemfile

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
```

config/database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Note: Because the way heroku works you can't use [sqlite](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3), use postgres instead

> SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk.
>   While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack
>   has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read
>   from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to
>   use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least
>   once every 24 hours.

Comment: I do have them defined beforehand. Is there perhaps a way to deploy with `sqlite3`? Most StackOverflow posts request I convert my database to postgresql

Comment: Before I change my database to `postgresql`, I would like to ask if the error messages do come from the fact that I'm using `sqlite3`. If so, how would you remedy it such that even if I do deploy it as `sqlite3`, it does work temporarily without the error messages.

Comment: The error comes because you have sqlite3 as your adapter on your database.yml, the rails new command has the option --skip-active-record to not load any ActiveRecord adapter